# Why can't I nest a tbody tag inside a div tag with JSX in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm a React beginner and I'm working on a project where I'll have a form and as data gets entered a table will be dynamically populated with data from the user.

**My code:**

```
<div>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.someData}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.moreData}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</div>
```

React is throwing this error: ValidateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of div

I tried putting the table inside a new component and then nesting the new component but I have the same problem. Why does JSX not like tables inside of divs? Is there any work-around?

Comment: Because as the error says TBODY doesn't belong in DIV it goes inside TABLE

Comment: You need to put `<tbody>` within a `<table>`.

Comment: By the way, your question title says "table" tag while your actual question is using a "tbody"

Comment: Error seems to be pretty self explanatory - permitted parents of `tbody`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is an HTML one. To make a table, the table body has to be inside the `<table>` tag:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

No table tag works without  tag.  should be under 
like :

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.someData}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.moreData}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```